# Display the name of the metadata navigation pane in library

Tags: managed-metadata-service

Is it possible to display the name of the section of the metadata navigation pane that you have just clicked in the web part to the right of the pane?  So each time you click on a new section the title updates according to that title?  See screenshot.[image: Nav]